# Are there Two exclusive locks on same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am inserting rows into single table from two instances and they are completing successfully.
When any transaction updating any table then it acquire 'Exclusive' on that Table (resource) and there must be single Exclusive lock on table while inserting data.

```
               Granted
Requested      Exclusive(X)    Shared(S)
Exclusive      NO              NO
Shared         NO              Yes
```

Creating Sample table:

```
create table TestTransaction
(
Colid int Primary Key,
name varchar(10)
)
```

Inserting Instance 1:

```
Declare @counter int =1
Declare @countName varchar(10)='te'
Declare @max int=1000000
while @counter<@max
Begin
insert into TestTransaction
values
(
@counter,
@countName+Cast(@counter as varchar(7))
)
Set @counter=@counter+1
End
```

Inserting Instance 2:

```
insert into TestTransaction 
values
(2000001,'yesOUTofT')
```

Why it is successful? 
At the same time retrieval (Select) from this table is not happening because of the lock on table.

Comment: Have you looked at what locks actually exists?

Answer (score 2):

> When any transaction updating any table then it acquire 'Exclusive' on that Table (resource) and there must be single Exclusive lock on table while inserting data.

That's a common myth. Locks in SQL Server are usually per-row. Various things cause them to escalate to page, partition or table level. SQL Server is designed, though, to try to lock at the smallest level first in order to allow for more concurrency.

Do not rely on any particular locking behavior in your apps if you can. Rather, make use of the isolation level setting if possible in order to obtain the required consistency guarantees you need.